# Linq : Unable to cast object of type 'system.double' to type 'system.string'

Tags: c#, linq

`Dt` contains LOADERID 300
                      CompanyName India

```
var test = from t in Dt.AsEnumerable()
           group t by t.Field<string>("LOADERID") into g
           select new
           { 
              cr = g.Key,
             count = g.Count(),
           };
```

On iterating through the linq result:

```
foreach(var temp in test) -> throwing error
{
//Code
}
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'system.double' to type 'system.string'

Please suggest what I am doing wrong.
Thanks

Comment: where are you using `temp`? Try to understand the meaning of the iteration here

Comment: Perhaps LOADERID is a double?

Comment: @KernelMode it is not going inside the foreach loop

Comment: So can you please explain how both piece of code related?

Comment: @RaymondChen LOADERID is string

Comment: Did you mean `group` (with lower case)? Assuming you are referring to `group` of `LINQ`

Comment: @KernelMode yes group with lower case

Comment: Instead of doing a lot of things at once, do them in steps. That way you can determine which step is raising the exception. (I still think it's because LOADERID is a double. That's the only obvious place where there is a forced cast to string, and `Field<T>` is documented as raising an `InvalidCastException` if the type does not match, rather than attempting a conversion.)

Comment: Change Field<string> to Field<double>

Answer (score 1):

From your data, `LOADERID = 300`, it's clear that you're trying to convert a `double` into `string`. You have to use the correct data type:

```
var test = from t in Dt.AsEnumerable()
           group t by t.Field<double>("LOADERID") into g
           select new
           { 
              cr = g.Key,
              count = g.Count(),
           };
```

Or, if the data type isn't important in subsequent code, you can just use the indexer instead of `Field<T>`:

```
var test = from t in Dt.AsEnumerable()
           group t by t["LOADERID"] into g
           select new
           { 
              cr = g.Key,
              count = g.Count(),
           };
```